# Still show database result even XAMPP not active

Tags: xampp, localhost

I have a web with registered user. Even when XAMPP is not active, the webpage still show data (example:registered user)? How the web retrieve the data?
*Alert: Newbie.

Comment: Maby is there running an other XAMPP on the background?

Comment: how do check that? which program running on background? xampp? can it?

Comment: Open your taskmanager (windowskey and then type "taskmanager")
If you see a task with "Xampp" then click on "end task".

Comment: that really basic, and i certainly already checked that. but still, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though the orange xampp icon may not appear in the systray (or appear running in the task manager), the Apache and MySQL processes, if they were set to run as services through xampp, may still be running.

You can open the xampp control panel to stop those services, if desired.

Comment: That solve it! Thank you Sir! 
But, how and where do I check if Apache and MySQL module still on (on my Windows PC)? Other than opening the XAMPP control panel?

Comment: If those services are running, those will appear in the task manager's "processes" list as apache and mysqld.You can even see those in the Windows services panel: services.msc, if typed into the run box. You can also use the services panel to stop those services too.

Comment: Thank you Sir!. Thats clear my confusion for days. Simple problem, but i gues i just didn't see it. Thank you again.