# apache error message when downloaded via xampp

Tags: apache, xampp

I installed XAMPP in order to use PHP, but I received the following error message via the control panel:

```
8:12:47 PM  [mysql] Problem detected!
8:12:47 PM  [mysql] Port 3603 in use by "Unable to open process"!
8:12:47 PM  [mysql] MySQL WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
8:12:47 PM  [mysql] You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
8:12:47 PM  [mysql] or reconfigure MySQL and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
```

I already have MYSQl donwloaded so I am not sure if the port is conflicting or what the issue may be. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: if you already have a running standalone mysql, you should use it instead of starting a different instance from xampp.

Comment: ...which is to say, don't start mysql in xampp in this case, the other already-installed instance will be used instead.

Comment: @BagusTesa ....thanks for the response. I only did it because I was having trouble donwloading PHP

Comment: @PaulT. ....thanks for the response. Can I still use PHp alone in XAMPP

Comment: What OS do you have? ... Depends on the configuration. If you do not already have PHP on the system, and are using what xampp provides, then that should be ok. I've done that in the past on a windows xampp install where I only started apache but not mysql since I already had mysql installed and running, and xampp found my already-installed reference/version when I opened phpmyadmin.

Comment: See my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42981134/7644018), if it may be helpful, where some one had some confusion of the system's service vs xampp.

Comment: @PaulT.  ....I am using Microsoft 11. I started the Apache port via the XAMPP control panel and it booted up. However, when I went to VSC and tried to add a new php file to an html document, I received the following error:"Cannot validate since a PHP Installation could not be found. Use thesetting 'php.validate.executablePath' to configure the PHP executable."     I even tried to save it into the XAMPP files and then run it in the browser but it didn't work.

Comment: @jumpman23 is your website located inside `xampp\htdocs` folder? you should check their faq page before going full leeroy on it. also, if you are using `php` as command line, it has to be registered to **windows path**.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set php executable path php.validate.executablePath in vscode when php is set inside docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43768614/how-to-set-php-executable-path-php-validate-executablepath-in-vscode-when-php-is)

Comment: @BagusTesa  ....thank you for your help. I will study the link that you gave me and find the answer. I do not know what a docker is...but I will find out.